# When your method needs a new parameter, but only in certain circumstance ...?

Tags: java, overloading

I have a method

```
myMethod(int a, String b)
```

that has been working fine. However, now I need it to perform some additional work when parameter *a* is of a certain value. In this situation an additional parameter needs to be passed in to the arguements.

Should I just change the method signature to

```
myMethod(int a, String b, int newParameter)
```

and pass in nulls in all the cases where this parameter is unnecessary?

Perhaps leaving the old method signature, and getting that to call the new method with a null parameter would be most convenient, so I don't have to change anything elsewhere in the code e.g.

```
myMethod(int a, String b) { return myMethod(a, b, null); }
```

Or do I need to look at this differently?

All comments are much appreicated!

---

UPDATE

```
myMethod(int a, String b)
```

does a whole bunch of stuff, including calling

```
anotherMethod()
```

the only difference that needs to happen when *newParameter* is included is that anotherMethod is called like so

```
anotherMethod(newParameter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO I think you are on the right track.  I usually leave the old method signature and call the method with the additional parameters.  If you look at commons code you will see the same technique used a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just overload the method `myMethod` that can take the additional parameter and call that **specific** method, when you need. Just make a call to the method what you need. I don't see any need to make an indirect call from the method to another over loaded method.

```
myMethod(int a, String b) { return myMethod(a, b, null); }
```

Here you are any how calling the overloaded method. Just change the code now it self to make the calls to the necessary method, else it will turn to be a mess the program when gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

If the calling method knows when the extra parameter is needed, then yes, I'd lean toward the second approach.  You see this all the time with constructors.  Alternately, if myMethod can be broken down into it's constituents, you could call the appropriaet constituent part depending on the value of 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

If your function needs to do two separate things, then you should make it two separate functions, yes.  I think this is much clearer than having one function which takes a "behaviour flag" kind of argument.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
myMethod(int a, String b) {

AnotherMethod();

}

myMethod(int a, String b, int newParameter) {

AnotherMethod(newParameter);

}
```

Alternative:

```
myMethod(int a, String b, int newParameter) {

if (newParameter != -1) 
{
AnotherMethod(newParameter);
} else {
AnotherMethod();
}
```

and let -1 be some value you will never use, representing "null"

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that leaving the old method signature, and getting that to call the new method with a null parameter would be the better option. I would just write smart code that would handle the case of "null" properly.

The less redundancy in your code, the easier its maintenance will be. Think about it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading can be best done like this:

```
/* Some value that is most common to use in your program. */
private final int DEFAULT_PARAM_VALUE = 0;

public void myMethod (int a, String b) {
    myMethod (a, b, DEFAULT_PARAM_VALUE);

public void myMethod (int a, String b, int newParameter) {
    /* do all your main stuff here */

    anotherMethod (newParameter);
}

public void anotherMethod (int param) {
    /* do other stuff */
}
```